# How to increment each digit in a variable by 5?

Tags: php

I need a php function that adds 5 to each number of a string given and go back to 0 once it reaches 10.

Let's say `$number = 281621` and so I need 5 added to each of those digits, the end result should look like:

```
736176
```

Each digit should go back to 0 once it reaches 10. How would we accomplish this?

Comment: It is possible but What is exactly meaning of this "Each digit should go back to 0 once it reaches 10" As above example you have added  5 in second digit so let say `8+5 = 13` but you have shown `3` only. Suppose sum comes to `10` then we have to show `0` as e.g. `55` will result in 00 right ?

Comment: No. 55 will result at 5. We will only take the unit digit.

Comment: So if you do it twice, it will go `281621` -> `736176` -> `281621`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does the thing.

```
    function addToNumber($number, $add){
        $string_number = strval($number);
        for($i = 0; $i < strlen($string_number); $i++)
            $string_number[$i] = strval((intval($string_number[$i]) + $add) % 10);
        return intval($string_number);
    }

    $number = 281621;

    echo addToNumber($number, 5);

?>
```

`addToNumber()` takes the number it self as its first argument and second argument is the number you want to add to each digit, in your case 5. It's pretty straight forward and I don't think an explanation is required but still if you have any doubts, leave it in the comments.

Comment: Thanks this is perfect!

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
<?php
$str=2356;
$newarr=array();
$arr1 = str_split($str);
foreach ($arr1 as $arr) {
   $newarr[]=($arr+5)%10;
}
print_r(join('',$newarr));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
<?php

$int = '281621';
$array = str_split($int);

foreach ($array as $num) {
    $new[] = ($num + 5) % 10;
}
echo $str = join('', $new);
?>
```